# Einstein Next Best Action Strategy Source "Flow Builder" doesnt pass recommendationId to flow

Tags: einstein-recommendations, lightning-flow-builder, flow-builder, einstein-next-best-action

I have a Einstein Next Best Action Component on my Opportunity Page Layout. I can choose the "Strategy Source" as "Strategy Builder" or "Flow Builder"

When I select "Flow Builder", I select my Recommendation Strategy Flow to return Recommendations, but when I click the "Accept" button on the Recommendation from the Opportunity Record, the "recommendationId" variable is not passed to the Recommendation Action Flow.

However if I select "Strategy Builder" as the Stratey Source, I return the same Recommendation from a Strategy Builder built Strategy, the "recommendationId" is passed to the Recommendation Action Flow.

I am using this "recommendationId" in the Recommendation Action Flow to read the Recommendation and retrieve some extra data that is used within the flow.

Flow Builder lets me do a lot more "logic" than Strategy Builder does (i.e. counting related records etc.) but just doesn't pass along the "recommendationId" variable. I am trying to avoid extra custom fields on Opportunity (i.e. countOfRelatedObject1__c, countOfRelatedObject2__c and others calculated properties used to filter the Recommendations)

Any ideas on how to solve this apart from using Strategy Builder, which seems more limited